# Notation question

Tags: time-series, covariance-matrix, vector-autoregression, notation

In what follows $\Phi$ is the autoregressive polynomial obtained in estimating a (noncausal) VAR model, $Y_t - \Phi Y_{t-1}$ is the error term from the VAR process and $Y_{t-h} - \Phi Y_{t-h-1}$ is a lagged error term of the same process.

Gourieroux and Jasiak (2017) "Noncausal vector autoregressive process: Representation, identification and semi-parametric estimation" published in the Journal of Econometrics, they write the following:

"...as long as the error terms (of the VAR) $\varepsilon_t$ are serially independent, there exist...nonlinear covariance based conditions that can be used, such as the covariances between nonlinear transforms of the error terms

$$c_{j, k}(h, \Phi) = Cov(a_j(Y_t - \Phi Y_{t-1}), a_k(Y_{t-h} - Y_{t-h-1}))$$

for

$$j,k = 1, ..., K,$$ $$ h = 1,...H. $$

defined for a given set of functions $a_k,$ k = 1, ..., K.

More precisely" (here is where my confusion begins) "let us denote by $\Psi_{l}(Y_t, \phi), l = 1, ... KH$, function $a_k(Y_{t-h} - \Phi Y_{t-h-1})$ where $\phi = vec(\Phi')$."

I can't, understand how one is able to define a series of functions $\Psi_{l} = a_k(Y_h - \Phi Y_{t-h-1})$ for an index $l = 1, ... KH$ when the LHS is indexed only by $l$ and the right hand side is indexed by both $k$ and $h$ (the index for $l$ runs up to $KH$ so maybe that's a hint?).

I also don't understand how $h$ is used in new definition. For example $\Psi_1 = a_k(Y_{t-h} - \Phi Y_{t-h-1})$ but also $\Psi_4 = a_k(Y_{t-h} - \Phi Y_{t-h-1}).$

Since the $\Psi_{l}$ function contains neither $h$ nor $k$ how does it act as an index?

The authors then go on to say "For each covariance $$c_{kl} = Cov(\Psi_{k}(Y_t, \psi), \Psi_{l}), $$ $$k, l = 1, ..., KH$$ we can write its sample counterpart."

Since both $k$ and $l$ run from $1, ..., KH$ are there $(KH)^2$ $c_{kl}$ covariances? Am I interpreting this correctly?